# Issue cropping images with pillow and discord.py

Tags: python, image, discord, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I'm currently trying to make a command for my bot that shows a rank card for the user. I've gotten their name and pfp successfully on the card, but ran into issues trying to crop the pfp to be circular. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def checkrank(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
  if user == None:
    user = ctx.author
  
  image = Image.open('Levels.png')
  
  titlefont = ImageFont.truetype('Poppins-SemiBold.ttf', 60)

  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

  asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
  data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
  pfp = Image.open(data)
  mask = Image.open(data).convert('L')
  pfp = pfp.resize((100,100))

  output = ImageOps.fit(pfp, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
  output.putalpha(mask)

  title = f'{user.name}'

  image.paste(pfp,(70,70))
  draw.text((200, 80), title, (0,0,0), font=titlefont)
  image.save('levelout.png')
```

When I run the command, everything works fine and I don't get any error messages, but the image stays as a square, and doesn't crop. I've successfully implemented circular cropped images into commands before, so I'm not really sure what I'm messing up here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in a line of your code.

```
pfp = pfp.resize((100,100))
```

This would give you a square shape, as you said, because 100 by 100 are the same dimensions and squares have the same sides. Maybe if you tweak the numbers here, your picture would be resized?

```
image.paste(pfp,(70,70))
```

Again, from my knowledge, this would make it a square yet again so maybe play around with these numbers too.

If you need anymore help feel free to reply.